# How to get the ID of the unique pendingIntent that is called by AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am building an alarm application. One of the features I am adding right now is the volume of the alarm. When the user is setting up the alarm, they can choose the volume of the alarm with a `SeekBar`. So, when the alarm goes off, the volume of it should be set to whatever the user set it to. To do this, I would need to know which specific alarm has been called. I have identified each `PendingIntent` with the id of the alarm from the database. My problem is I just don't know how to retrieve this id again once the alarm goes off.

As you can see, this is how I identify each the PendingIntent by passing in `alarm.getID()`:

```
PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
ChangeAlarmActivity.this, (int)alarm.getID(), alarmIntent, 0);
```

So in my activity that is called when the alarm goes off I want to do something like

```
int id = pendingIntent.getID();
Alarm alarm = database.getAlarm(id);
int volume = alarm.getVolume();
```

How do I therefore get the unique identifier of a PendingIntent within an Activity that is called after the alarm is turned on? In other words, how do I know which alarm is being set off?

Answer (score 1):

In first place, forgive me for my english, it's not very good.
I think that you most likely already found out a solution for this issue, but I had the same doubt and I couldn't figure out the answer easily. So after many researches I figure out a way. For retrieve a ID from the alarm fired is possible put a ID on intent:

`// create intent
 Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyClass.class);
 // store id
 intent.putExtra("id", yourId);`

And after this, use this intent for create the PendingIntent, that going to setting up the alarm. When the alarm fire off, the method `onReceive(context, intent)` will receive the intent used for create the PendingIntent, thus the id can be retrieve on the method:

`// retrieves id
 long id = intent.getLongExtra("id", -1);`

I hope that be useful!